# Function create_function() is deprecated PHP 7.2.1

Tags: deprecated, create-function

since I update I get this messege but I just used a Snippet in this case and do not understand the code. There fore I do not know to change it to be right. 
Can someone help me with this please?

Code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_notices', $c = create_function( '', 'echo "' . addcslashes( $msg, '"' ) . '";' ) );
```

Thank you for your time. as soon i get a glimpse of what  I am doing, I will help other too.

Answer (score 0):

My Solutions that work for me:

```
<?php
echo $msg; //this is new line and delete or deactivate the other

//add_action( 'admin_notices', $c = create_function( '', 'echo "' . addcslashes( $msg, '"' ) . '";' ) );
```

Comment: This is not really a solution, just hiding the code. This post might help you: [Function create_function() is Deprecated in PHP 7.2 - How to Migrate?](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/12/17/function-create-function-is-deprecated-in-php-72-how-to-migrate/)